# Don't know how to Copy files to SD card in Genymotion Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, emulation, genymotion

I want to put some files at my virtual SD Card in Genymotion Android Emulator, running custom tablet with Android 4.2.2.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You may want to consider reading the information you explicitly agreed to when creating your account regarding how to ask questions here. You can review this information in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you can simply drag and drop the files onto the running emulator. I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, i clicked on DDMS, selected my Emu by clicking and put the items in my virtual SD Card Folder.

Comment: drag and drop. brilliant!